# Centering group of divs as responsive site header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking at using the jQuery random fade in for a site header. The divs stack as I want when changing the viewport size (all in a row at full size, stacking up to 3x3 as the screen gets smaller). However, I can't figure out how to have this group of divs centre on the page>

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#boxset div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
#boxset div p {
  margin: 0;
  background: #290052;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*display: none;*/
  padding-top: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="boxset">
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">A</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">B</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">C</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">D</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">E</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">F</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">G</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">H</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">I</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Before answer, may i ask if you really need both the div and the p element?

Comment: I'm using the p element to control the appearance of text within the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#boxset {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:0;
}
#boxset div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display: inline-block;

}
#boxset div p {
  margin: 0;
  background: #290052;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*display: none;*/
  padding-top: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="boxset">
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">A</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">B</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">C</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">D</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">E</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">F</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">G</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">H</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><a href="index.html">I</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use display: inline-block; instead of float, and then text-align: center; on the parent:

```
#header {
    text-align: center;
}
#header div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as I have, without the fix for the extra spacing between items, and you place text-align center on header instead of boxset.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't see yours before I posted mine.